# A question about two analytic functions $f$ and $g$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-functions

This particular question was asked in my complex analysis assignment and I am asking for proof verification here.

> **Question**: Is following statement true or false? Justify. Let $f,g :\mathbb{C}  \to \mathbb{C} $ be complex analytic and let $ h: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be a non-constant continuous map. Suppose $f(z)=g(z)$ for every $z \in \text{Im}(h)$, then $f=g$.

As $[0,1]$ is compact so $\text{Im}(h)$ would be compact and not singleton. So, every sequence in $\text{Im}(h)$ would have convergent subsequence whose limit is also in $\text{Im}(h)$. So, I can use identity theorem to prove that $f=g$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: The identity theorem does, indeed, give the proof. It would even suffice if $h$ were defined only on $\{0\}\cup \{2^{-n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura Just saying the the range of $h$ is compact and not  singelton does not guarantee that the range has limit points.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It is also *given* $\;h\;$ is continuous and non-constant. Mabe I'd remark that but perhaps it is unnecessary and thus Im$\,h\;$ must be a non-trivial closed interval.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It is given from the beginning that $\;h\;$ is non-constant...and I suppose you meant $\;h\;$ and not Im$\,h\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio $h$ is not real valued. It is complex valued so the image need not be   a closed interval. (in my earlier comment I had read $Im h$ as imginary part of $h$ and I have deleted that comment now).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Now I know what you meant...but anyway: if a complex valued function is analytic and has imaginary (real) part constant then the whole function is constant.

Comment: @DonAntonio read the question again. $h$ is not analytic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not correct. $\{1,2\}$ is compact and not a singleton but it has no limit points. You have to use the connectedness of the range of $h$ to say that there is a limit point.

[Any continuous map from a connected space into a discrete space is a constant].

Comment: Could you please elaborate why the range of h must have a limit point in C?

Comment: but the range need not be an interval...it is a subset of the complex plane. You have mentioned this point in one of your comments above

Comment: @RagingBull The range of either the real part of $h$ or the imaginary part of $f$ is an interval with at least two points.

Comment: i am having trouble understanding this claim...are you using some kind of characterization of connected sets in the complex plane?

Comment: @RagingBull If  a subset of the complex palne contains a line segment (which is not a single point) then it has limit points. Any point in the middle of the line segement is a limit point.

Comment: Now it is clear to me...thanks a lot :-)